# Prediction using multiple training sets

Tags: prediction, validation, model-averaging

I have multiple different training sets ($TS_1$, $TS_2$, .., $TS_n$) and one test set ($TS$).  I have calculated the prediction measures precision, recall, and F-measure for each pair ($TS_n$, $TS$).

Is there any statistical method that can combine the prediction measures calculated for the different training sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in economic forecasting it's done all the time, look at this recent paper [Combining Forecasts with Many Predictors](http://www.faculty.ucr.edu/~taelee/paper/wmu.pdf)

this may not be directly applicable to your field. from the problem description it seems to me the most straightforward way is to simply merge all $TS_i$ into one training set.